# visual studio code download link broken?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm tring to download MicroSoft's "[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)"

On the download page https://code.visualstudio.com/download, after I clicked ".deb [64 bit](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb)", it directed to the download page but nothing happened after display:

> Thanks for downloading VS Code for Linux! Download not starting? Try
>   this [direct download link](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/latest/linux-deb-x64/stable). Please take a few seconds and help us
>   improve ... click to take survey.

If I click on thee "direct download link", the page shows

> Not Found

Is it i missed somthing.. or microsoft website got hiccups?

Comment: Report it to Microsoft

Comment: Yup, I see the same "Not Found" for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with their CDNs. Definitely needs to be reported. If you are in a hurry, the [MajorGeeks mirror](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/visual_studio_code.html) has the 32bit download:

Comment: thanks. i prefer a 64bit version, nvm, will wait microsoft to wake up.

Answer (score -1):

It also happened to me. I was not able to download it because the page always shows "This site can’t be reachedaz764295.vo.msecnd.net took too long to respond.". I guess it is a glitch in the windows page itself. I will wait and give it another attempt after sometime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).